H-NMR: Why are coupling and integration values not matching?
I am trying to synthesize Ethyl 2-(triphenylphosphoranylidene)propionate.
I recently ran an NMR which is attached below. 
I am ignoring impurities for now.
Considering the ethyl group, the number of peaks is correct. There are quartets for ylene and ylide form at about 3.5 to 4.3 ppm and a triplet at about 0.45 ppm. This matches the expected coupling.
However, the integrals are identical, which is untypical for an ethyl group where there should be a ratio of 2 : 3.
What reason might there be for the integrals to be identical while the coupling is as expected?
Edit:
I provided an answer to my original question below. However, my research raised new questions. As Mathew Mahindaratne rightfully pointed out in the comment section, a ylide simply is a resonance structure of the ylene and therefore the same molecule. However, the paper I referenced showed the chemical shifts for major and minor forms of the hydrogen atoms. I am also trying my best to tackle this issue below.

You cannot ignore impurities here because they are significant (e.g., check integral value for the multiplet at around $\delta 1.0-1.5$, which is clearly due to presence of some impurity).

I am aware of these impurities. In the case you mentioned, the multiplet should belong to cyclohexane, which has been used to wash the product in the last step.
However, in this particular case, my issue is that the desired integral at 0.45 ppm is smaller than expected, not larger, so impurities are not a valid explanation.
The triphenylphosphoryl group, for example, at about 7.5 ppm, should have an integral of about 15, however, I am pretty sure there will be impurities in this multiplet, maybe even CDCl₃, which has been used as a medium for H-NMR.

I made a close look at your spectrum with expansion. It seems you have integrated methylene peak of ethyl group with some impurity peak (I originally thought it was an isomeric peak) and put it as 2 protons. That plays a significant role in value difference. In reality, ratio looks like 1.5:2.00 to me.

Thank you. I was interpreting these quartets as both the ylide and ylene form, thus resulting in a different chemical shift.  I integrated them both as I interpreted them as different structures of the same product. So you are basically saying the smaller of the two quartets might not be the ylide form, but rather an impurity?

Ylide and ylene are resonance forms of same structure (see here and here). Thus, the smaller quartet you are talking about is most probably an impurity (may be hydrolyzed form of one of starting material?).

Thank you for the clarification. I have posted an answer and provided additional information which answered my original question about the integrals.
However, the paper also mentions the same quartet at 4.06 ppm so it might not be an impurity. Since you rightfully pointed out that ylide and ylene are resonance forms of the same structure, I am still clueless why there is an additional quartet at 4.06 ppm, an additional duplet at 1.60 ppm and an additional triplet at 1.25 ppm.

I think you should include all those information (in all of your comments) in the question you posted (may be as late edit). That would improve the question and easy for reader who wanted to answer.

I finally found the answer to my question on page 88 of supporting information to the first reference[1], which gives the $^1\ce{H}$-NMR data as follows:

$(\pu{400 MHz}, \ce{CDCl3})$: 7.75-7.20 (m, 15 H), 4.06 (q, J = 7.0, 2H minor), 3.72 (q, J = 7.0, 2H major), 1.62 (d, J = 16.7, 3H major), 1.60 (d, J = 16.7, 3H minor), 1.25 (t, J = 7.0, 3H minor), 0.45 (t, J = 7.0, 3H major)

There is a minor triplet to be expected at $\delta = \pu{1.25 ppm}$ which overlaps with cyclohexane in my case and has not been integrated. Thus, the integral value for the $\ce{CH3}$-part of the ethyl group should in fact be higher than 2.00 when added with the minor part as described above.
Edit:
The question, what exactly the major and minor form are, still remained. The second paper[2] suggests E/Z isomerism in a different phosphorus ylide. Applied to Ethyl 2-(triphenylphosphoranylidene)propionate, we should end up with a situation like this: 

References:

Denmark, S. E.; Kobayashi, T.; Regens, C. S. Total synthesis of (+)-papulacandin D. Tetrahedron 2010, 66 (26), 4745-4759. DOI: 10.1016/j.tet.2010.03.093

Najaf, M.; Marandi, G. Synthesis of novel organophosphorus compounds via reaction of substituted 2‑oxoindoline‑3‑ylidene with acetylenic diesters and triphenylphosphine or triphenyl phosphite. Scientific Reports 2024, 14, 6314. DOI: 10.1038/s41598-024-56774-z


